# SQL Выборка товаров из таблицы, исходя из характеристик в другой таблице

Tags: mysql, sql

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть 2 таблицы: 1 - товары, 2 - характеристики товара, 3 - коллекции
В 1й таблице поля: id, title, collection_id
Во 2й - id, product_id, title, value
В 3й - id, title

Есть 2 способа отображения на сайте: отображение сразу товаров и отображение коллекций товарами.
На сайте есть блоки сортировки по характеристикам (область применения, цвет и тд). В каждом блоке характеристик товары могут иметь несколько значений, например, область применения товара - и для ванной и для гостиной. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно составить запрос для вывода подходящих товаров по выбранным параметрам в сортировке?! А так же вывод коллекций, товары в которых удовлетворяют выбранным параметрам в сортировке. (для другого варианта отображения).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT products.*
                FROM products, characteristics, collections
                WHERE products.id=characteristics.product_id
                AND products.collection_id = collections.id
                AND characteristics.value='red'
                AND collections.title = 'dress';
```